# GNU make: Why target is always running?

Tags: makefile

Below is the example makefile.

If syn output is not changed, ila shall not run.
Don't understand why ila is always running.

```
DEBUG_FILE = ./debug/debug.txt
INPUTS0 = syn.tcl

OUTPUTS0 = syn.out
OUTPUT_ILA = $(DEBUG_FILE)

############################################################################
#
# Dependencies / rules
#
############################################################################
ifdef DEBUG_FILE
all: ila
else
all: syn
endif

## Synthesis
$(OUTPUTS0): $(INPUTS0)
    echo "Synthesis Process."
    touch $(OUTPUTS0)

$(OUTPUT_ILA): $(OUTPUTS0)
    echo "Debug Probe Insertion."
    touch $(OUTPUT_ILA)


syn: $(OUTPUTS0)
ila: $(OUTPUT_ILA)
```

- First run:

> -> make
>   echo "Synthesis Process."
>   Synthesis Process.
>   touch syn.out
>   echo "Debug Probe Insertion."
>   Debug Probe Insertion.

- Second run:

> -> make
>   echo "Debug Probe Insertion."
>   Debug Probe Insertion.

Because $(OUTPUT_ILA) should be newer than $(OUTPUTS0). I'm not expecting ila is running at second time.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show example runs of `make` that does the wrong thing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Can you simplify the makefile at all, while preserving the error?

Comment: Seems 'touch $(OUTPUT_ILA)' doesn't create the new file. So ila is keep running.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a file `ila`. The `make` assumes you want create a file `ila` which should newer than `$(OUTPUT_ILA)`.

Comment: Not quite understand, could you give me more details. Why syn is running without problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having a problem with this?
I cannot reproduce this error. For me, the $(OUTPUT_ILA) recipe runs only the first time. (or if syn.out or syn.tcl are updated)
My guess is that you were deleting the debug.txt file in between runs.

Note that you can use the trace and debug flags to more easily determine why `make` tries to remake certain targets. (You will get a lot of extraneous output about searching for implict rules, unless you also disable built-in rules with the third flag you see below.)

Run this:

```
make --trace -d --no-builtin-rules
```

or

```
make --trace -d --no-builtin-rules [<TARGET>]
```